# Error in Cloud-Connetion for connection with my BD(SQL Server 2012 Express)

Tags: sql-server, gooddata, cloud-connect

I'm brazilian and my english is very bad, so sorry, rs

I'm trying to create a cloud-connection with SqlServer connection but is showing an error when performed the connection validation.
Error:
Can not connect to DB: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

Filled fields:
User: sa
Pass: 
URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433/TOTVALE11
JDBC specific: MS SQL server 2008-2012
* My sql server is SQL Server 2012 express

I'm try:
 - Enable remote access to the database
 - Enable SQL-Server port in firewall Windows
But without success

Link used for configuration:
https://developer.gooddata.com/article/cloudconnect-working-with-databases

Does anyone know what could be?

Obrigado por enquanto

Abraço

Answer (score 0):

The error message ususally refers to the issue of the **dynamic port** server **settings**. Try to go to *Windows-Start->Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 20xx->Configuration Tools->SQL-ServerConfiguration-Manager*. Once the tool starts go to *SQL-Server-Network-config -> protocols for [instance name]*, Open TCP/IP at right site, Choose the IP-Adresses and Scroll down to IP All. Insert in the field for TCP-Port your port 1433 and Restart SQL-Server service.